# What will be the deficits when left half of the brain is removed in adults?

Tags: brain

Hemispherectomy is a surgical procedure to remove half of the brain. It is typically done on children with severe epilepsy. What will be the deficits when left half is removed in adults? Is aphasia a certain outcome in case of left hemispherectomy in adults?